# How To Group By With Condition

Tags: mysql

I have a design_category_table

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Id        | IdDesign | IdCategory |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1         | 1        | 1          |
| 2         | 1        | 2          |
| 3         | 2        | 1          |
| 4         | 2        | 2          |
| 5         | 2        | 3          |
| 6         | 3        | 1          |
| 7         | 3        | 2          |
| 8         | 3        | 3          |
| 9         | 3        | 4          |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

1) I want to Group by IdDesign With Condition List Of IdCategory Contains (1 AND 2 AND 3)

result will be display 2 row only

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Id        | IdDesign | IdCategory |
+-----------+----------+------------+
|3          | 2        | 1          |
|6          | 3        | 1          |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

2) I want to Group by IdDesign With Condition List Of IdCategory Equals(1 AND 2 AND 3)

result will be display 1 row only

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Id        | IdDesign | IdCategory |
+-----------+----------+------------+
|3          | 2        | 1          |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Please Help Me ... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=258f67d54ca8263c8e0fc16c2a63404c)

```
select min(Id) as Id,IdDesign,min(IdCategory)
from tablename
where IdCategory in (1,2,3)
group by IdDesign
having count(distinct IdCategory)>=3
```

OUTPUT:

```
Id  IdDesign    IdCategory
3     2          1
6     3          1

select min(id) as id, min(IdDesign) as IdDesign,IdCategory  
from
(  
select min(Id) as Id,IdDesign,min(IdCategory)
    from tablename
    where IdCategory in (1,2,3)
    group by IdDesign
    having count(distinct IdCategory)>=3
)A group by IdCategory
```

Comment: thank you ! i worked with my question 1 ! and how about my question 2 ?

Comment: @Cyan, I've updated answer for your 2nd question - you can check now